# Except block is not executed

Tags: python, dictionary, key, try-catch

I am tryng to make a function that has as parameters 2 dictionaries and uses a try block to update one of them but if I enter a wrong key nothing happens from the except.

```
try:
    player[item['Type']] = item['Name']
except: 
    player['Weapon'] = item['Name']
```

basically *item* is a dictionary that holds type, name, price, armour. If it is of type helmet then the player's helmet will be updated, but the item might be a weapon (types:  staff, sword) and the player has "weapon" as key so there will be a key error and I want the code to update player['Weapon'] but my except never runs

I printed  player[item['Type']] before the if and I do get an error.

Comment: Please, post [mre]

Comment: You say you get an error when trying to access non-existing key from the dictionary. You are not accessing it in this code, you're creating a new key:value pair in the dictionary, so you never get an error. After this line of code `player[item['Type']] = item['Name']` the player dictionary will have `item['Type']` key no matter if it did or did not before.

Comment: Thnak you, I thought I can only update using .update()